# Could you use two (or more) weather balloons, and an oxygen tank to get a human to low orbit?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight

1. Would it be possible?
2. Could you survive?
3. Practical?

Comment: There are many questions about balloons on this site, I recommend you use the site's search to familiarize yourself with them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could it be possible to launch a rocket from a balloon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1635/could-it-be-possible-to-launch-a-rocket-from-a-balloon)

Comment: There is no mention of any rocket here, not really a duplicate, but too broad/unclear to answer. It is good advice to read other  balloon-related questions *and especially their answers* first.

Answer (score 7):

No. Reaching low orbit requires a horizontal velocity of almost 8 km/s (17500 mph).  The balloons won't provide any velocity aside from that of the atmosphere they're floating in, which tops out at about 70 m/s (150 mph) in a strong jetstream.

Comment: Ok. Well what about just reaching that point. The altitude of low orbit.

Comment: @SamuelStrachan: Record altitude for a balloon is around 180K feet, or a little over 30 miles.  Typical orbits start at around 100 miles.  Answer's still no.

Answer (score 1):

No. A low orbit must be above the atmosphere, but you could not leave the atmosphere with a balloon. A low orbit needs a high horizontal velocity but a balloon just moves with the wind but does not accelerate on its own. The height of a low orbits is at least 200 km, but a balloon only about 30 km. As Pericynthion wrote, a velocity of about 8 km/s is necessary, but a balloon is very, very slow in comparison. Besides that, the direction of the velocity is important.

Comment: Ok. Well what about just reaching that point. The altitude of low orbit.

Comment: You need an atmosphere for a ballon. LEO is in space @SamuelStrachan